# Insert and update same table with transactions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Since I can't/don't know how to auto_increment two columns in one table I trying to do this with transactions. This is what I trying

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();
try 
{
       $sql = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password, firstname, lastname, email, user_image, path)
                    VALUES (:username, :password, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :user_image, :path)";

       $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
       $q->execute(array(
                    ':username' => $username,
                    ':password' => sha1($password),
                    ':firstname'    => $firstname,
                    ':lastname' => $lastname,
                    ':email'    => $email,
                    ':user_image'   => $forDB,
                    ':path'     => $path,
                    ));                     

       $lastInsertID = $pdo->lastInsertId();
       $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (usertype) 
                            VALUE (:user_id)");
       $sql->execute(array(
                    ':user_id'      => $lastInsertID
                    ));
       $pdo->commit();      
            }               
                // any errors from the above database queries will be catched
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                    // roll back transaction
                    $pdo->rollback();
                    // log any errors to file
                    ExceptionErrorHandler($e);
                exit;
            }
```

So basically I want to insert in column `usertype` the ID of this record (user_id) both columns must be equal. 
Now when I try with this .. it is save empty fields except for the `usertype` which is updated with `lastInsertID`

Comment: i don't see beginstransaction

Comment: Updated with full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (usertype) 
                    VALUE (:user_id)");
```

to this

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET usertype=:user_id WHERE user_id=:user_id");
```